# Change type of interface property based on other property

Tags: typescript

I am working on a grid (in React) and I have the following type and interfaces ([you can load the code here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAiBDGGDiUCWAJgMIQA2ArgLYB2AKsqgLxwDkAxhVFMDe4qzgAfNoSzBBI1jWoAjYFElsYoGKwDcAKE34aKqADMM7VMS48%20iUpVoB5MDHwQaAZzgBvTXDgvEVWeQAXD4wBDQA5loAvtq6%20kYm6OLW1DT2js5unt4G0FRYwS6hupGaMTp6CgmoAHJyCil2Dk6uHl5whMDs%20PlkAAoQcYXFEVreMAAWEBQuGDSEAMrAYBhQWNDDYaXlSChwdKqNac2ZcCzuUVqaoJCwcHFVxqiY2HhER205%20MBkhJslYzgZAw8jI-1G7UcMDIwHBpW87HIqXSLRcAH5ghd1HAAPQ4uDAfCTBRwMzcXj8I4ozIAGiSKipJ1cdLq-gaSKaGVa0H2hw5xy5blkGBcwEIcGcCAmqAARLtgDK4GAoBAULBEJDGBj6bgCCR%20QwUNFtDdoPAHoYnjq3uLsnBETZXMEXrr3vyANoAXUBKoA7i5ggAlLrQQgAHiKWzpFBoAGsaBBfTQAHxe42aRGueAO1LOrCu-WOs6fOAGb6-YKsIisGntYGgysASTQNchRJhTZbtfGjErYhUrYR-OpTpLOTyBTYAE0Z1OALRUKhzwiEQdwKK1y5AA)):

```
export type DataGridColumnType = 'currency' | 'date' | 'number' | 'text';

interface CurrencyColumnOptions {
  symbol: string;
}

interface DateColumnOptions {
  format: string;
}

interface NumberColumnOptions {
  decimalPoint: string;
  thousandSeparator: string;
}

type TextColumnOptions = {};

export interface DataGridColumn {
  field: string;
  label: string;
  title: string;
  columnOptions?: {}; // either CurrencyColumnOptions, DateColumnOptions, NumberColumnOptions or TextColumnOptions based on the "type" property
  type?: DataGridColumnType;
}

export interface DataGrid {
  columns: DataGridColumn[];
  rows: Record<string, unknown>[];
}

const column: DataGridColumn = {
  field: 'id',
  label: 'ID',
  title: 'ID',
  type: 'date',
  columnOptions: {
    format: 'YYYY-mm-dd',
  },
};
```

I would like to change the type of the property `columnOptions` in `DataGridColumn` based on the value of `type`, so that when "type" is "date", it would use DateColumnOptions for the `columnOptions` property.

I am aware that I could create a generic here, but these interfaces are a few layers deep inside of my grid system, and having a generic would make using the grid a lot more complicated.

I have looked around, but I am not sure of the correct terms to search for.

Is this something that can be done? Or would I have to create multiple interfaces and use union types?

Thank you

Comment: Define an interface like `IColumnType` which will store all common data shared between those types. This way, you can assign any type to `columnOptions` as long as the type you're assigning implements the interface `IColumnType`. Isn't this an option? It might be useful to add those types here

Comment: It is indeed an option, but I would have hoped to have something more strict. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TS Playground (link to IDE with your code)](//tsplay.dev/w6BQ6w), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  There should not be unrelated issues like unimported/undeclared types/values; also, what types do you want `columnOptions` to be? This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: @jcalz I updated the question, and added a link to typescriptlang.org. Thank you

Comment: You pretty much need unions or generics.  [Here](https://tsplay.dev/WPjMZN) is one way of using a programmatically generated discriminated union for `DataGridColumn`; does that work for you? Since `interface`s cannot themselves be unions, you may want to refactor this so that your `type`/`columnOptions` properties are pushed down one level like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8AQEN) so that it *holds* a union instead of *being* a union.  If either of those works for you I'm happy to write up an answer.  If not then let me know what the issue is so I can address it.

Comment: @jcalz The code from the first link you provided does exactly what I need (haven't tried the second one, but I'm guessing it works too). I will gladly accept this as an answer if you add it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to constrain two or more properties of an object type in some way, you will either need to make that object type a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the acceptable configurations, or a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type where the constrained properties depend in some way on the generic type parameter.

In your example, the `type` property is a [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html) and you use it to determine the type of the `columnOptions` property.  This is an ideal use case for a [*discriminated union*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), with `type` as the *discriminant*.

---

First: an `interface` cannot be a union type; so if you want `DataGridColumn` to be a discriminated union, you will need to make it a [`type` alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) instead; that's probably fine, but there are a few [differences between `type` aliases and `interface`s](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces).

Now you could manually write out `DataGridColumn` as a union explicitly, but this will be annoying and redundant:

```
// Don't do this
type DataGridColumn = {
    field: string;
    label: string;
    title: string;
    type: "number";
    columnOptions?: {
        decimalPoint: string;
        thousandSeparator: string;
    };
} | {
    field: string;
    label: string;
    title: string;
    type: "currency";
    columnOptions?: {
        symbol: string;
    } 
} | { // sigh, I'm bored, forget it
```

Instead you could refactor a bit and get use some type manipulation to get the compiler to define `DataGridColumn` programmatically in terms of some non-redundant types:

First we can make an interface for the truly common fields:

```
interface BaseDataGridColumn {
  field: string;
  label: string;
  title: string;
}
```

Then we can define the mapping between `type` and `columnOptions` where we use `type` as a key and `columnOptions` as a value:

```
interface DataGridColumnOptions {
  currency: {
    symbol: string;
  },
  date: {
    format: string;
  }
  ,
  number: {
    decimalPoint: string;
    thousandSeparator: string;
  },
  text: {}
}
```

Note that we don't intend to ever have a value of type `DataGridColumnOptions`; we're just going to use it to define `DataGridColumn`:

```
type DataGridColumnType = keyof DataGridColumnOptions;

type DataGridColumn = { [K in DataGridColumnType]: BaseDataGridColumn & {
  type: K,
  columnOptions?: DataGridColumnOptions[K]
}}[DataGridColumnType]
```

First we recreate your `DataGridColumnType` by taking the keys of `DataGridColumnOptions`, and then we generate the `DataGridColumn` union by [mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the `DataGridColumnType` properties.  We assign each key `K` to be the `type` property, and each value `DataGridColumnOptions[K]` to be the `columnOptions` property.  We [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) that pair of properties with the `BaseDataGridColumn` interface to get the extended type (intersecting acts like extending an interface, but it works programmatically). We then [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) this mapped type with `DataGridColumnType` to turn the mapped type into the discriminated union we want.

You can verify that this works as desired:

```
const column: DataGridColumn = {
  field: 'id',
  label: 'ID',
  title: 'ID',
  type: 'date',
  columnOptions: {
    format: 'YYYY-mm-dd',
  },
}; // okay

const badColumn: DataGridColumn = {
  field: 'id',
  label: 'ID',
  title: 'ID',
  type: 'currency',
  columnOptions: {
    format: 'YYYY-mm-dd', // error!
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    //Type '{ format: string; }' is not assignable 
    //to type '{ symbol: string; }'.
  },
};
```

---

That's the main approach I'd possibly take here.  If that works for you, great.  There are a few other changes and refactorings you might want to make to simplify or display things differently, but I won't go further along that route unless pressed.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QCJzHAcSmABMBhAewBsBXAWxGQG8AoZZGYCKkgLmQxhiIAOYBuNsipwARt36Dh4yWGBgqEBUNDKAvixahIsRClz4ipSrQYB5AA6qKIDM0kIaUKBBAIAnvys7OwYfnQy1FpKEuy6ADSSJHiabsEcFFB0eFE6Mcj67AnsIPRyUIGS7CQQCMBZVAAKFEY5onnsYAAWFDQYcCAkAMoQ9nBQeBmtyrFFyJAAHmCB+vosYH72ZniExOTU9CAAKhsoALzIANYQfhQwyOY7Vvt2jsDOGBJrJ-fblns2jHOTGQAG0ANLIUA-Cy7awHY6bAC6-HQWAefzhDGQADJUnMTvwwbMEM8QA4nC4APz8dGw0nkt4ucGIli6ZAAegAVMgIIsfCRXKAYNBkLZkJTmKCGpDGFcbndbMjRSCGoj8sh+CAIAA3EWc9n5EG0p4AhEQFksLn4zbQx7-A7IIGVDhcHhTdpSWTyATaNrO1TqFKKXL+gnIABEJXC0HDHpJAIZ72peLSVRqdTgjWa4HdzrSXR6fQGw1G4zAkx90WdbIAPsgaAMIJwtSQJLWUy7uHxKyG0tI5FRc-m1Boh8F1pt+OGPF4fP5Y874wdE1SKqngqFwpEe360u2G9VmxBW6zkHWgsEAHTXttnjvXy+3-UGEkuMDIJcMGm-OkAx14zgu34AByUhgNmftvWAgBJbBwJUEcUhguDZgnJCkkgeD2E-MlXneNdghgDIsiWZBgIATUo8iAFo6DoaiSBILD8gSXQxA5A0KAuOA-Bfd53xkOB7S-W0MVJf8L0At0yLAiCvUHMjYOYgNR0UlCVDDYCZ28Xw-GYnCVwwAj2CIzJsjIqiaLohimLiDieS8DIAEJnXZdkAD9PK87yfK81z2TNMjgVMkj3XyYDIVcEAKHfTAMGAEQQFkDRkH88trRQYDgU3CIFODNpwsvSR4lZT4kroCAMFGJBkAAJSbRByygQ4KEGHQNGg8BoHgJAAAlqBIHQAFUQEZNxJCMbrTFE39lzwlwO20ucAg7EIwlyscZmdDCUgvNIQvM-LpmCApglmYpSmgYzgmqWp6iaFod2O-Nul6fohhGMYJnKJ6PRK-NeVIphTtWDpvmNYSjm+c45VuGaTTmikPgMMGbTNABBAZDIk0EIShCHMShpFrrQwlzo-el5owZMCcppHmWKw1adNE4LXYSaTBq5mHT2ztpKOj1ILy31nrmRDNoyzGSEM-gMaxqnioMCaus5rYYVIRbSSM+HIZBREPSgCgAHdtfqkkoBIAAeI67IbC5oqNkAAD49byUGKbfCmAW-dXIYk50pO7UDbOdIWQKU8mVKQiPQ02KWZdWjKQJ25i0gMqnrv24jzIoqjaPoxjU5O6tis+XQgA)

Answer (score 0):

I guess thats not what you was thinking of, but it might help.

You can use `typeof` to declare a var.

```
let var1: string = 'asd';
let var2: typeof var1; // var2 is a string
```

according to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html

Answer (score 0):

Define an interface like `IColumnType` which will store all common data shared between those types. This way, you can
assign any type to `columnOptions` as long as the type you're assigning implements the interface `IColumnType`.

**OR**

Use generic programming. Something like this:

```
export interface DataGridColumn<T>{
  field: string;
  label: string;
  title: string;
  columnOptions?: T;
  component?: React.ReactNode;
  type?: DataGridColumnType;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
let dgc = new {
  ...
} as DataGridColumn<DataGridColumnType>;
```